# Можно ли в Android вызвать фонарик фронтальной камеры?

Tags: java, android

У телефона samsung galaxy a6 имеется фронтальная камера со своей вспышкой. То есть фонарики есть с двух сторон. Можно ли как-то в приложении вызвать фронтальную вспышку, чтобы она включалась по кнопке?
Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки фонарики включались с двух сторон телефона, то есть и задний и фронтальный?

Comment: В Android Studio нельзя, в Android можно

Comment: то есть мне, как новичку в программировании, это реализовать не получится

Comment: Android Studio - программа для написания приложений для андроида. У неё нет ни камеры, ни фонарика. Научитесь различать.

Comment: Я прекрасно понимаю что это такое, просто не совсем правильно выразился с точки зрения русского языка. Я имел в виду можно ли с помощью Android Studio написать приложение для вызова фронтального фонарика.

Comment: С помощью Android Studio можно написать любое приложение для андроида, которое позволяют технические возможности. И для фонарика тоже.

Comment: Вообще это делается через параметры самой камеры (через вспышку): `Camera.Parameters` ну а дальше, чтобы включить `params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);`, чтобы выключить: `params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делается это так:

1. Получаем ссылку на `CameraManager`, через `cameraManager=(CameraManager) getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE);`
2. Получаем список всех камер `cameraManager.getCameraIdList()`
3. Далее пробегаемся по всем камерам и запрашиваем `cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(String cameraId)`
4. В полученном объекте класса `CameraCharacteristics` запрашиваем свойство `LENS_FACING`, если свойство равно `FRONT` - значит это фронтальная камера
5. Далее запрашиваем свойство `FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE`, если `true` - значит камера имеет вспышку
6. Теперь уже можно включить вспышку выбранной камеры `cameraManager.setTorchMode(сameraId, true)`

Comment: Что нужно вписывать на место cameraId? Откуда брать значение?
cameraManager.setTorchMode(сameraId, true)

Comment: По моему это уже наглость так спрашивать, неужели трудно зайти и посмотреть документацию `getCameraIdList()` или просто понять по контексту?!

Comment: в onCreate я не могу получить cameraId, он там просто неизвестен, так как находится в конструкции boolean hasFlashForFrontCamera. Мне нужно как-то достать оттуда это значение, а я сильно туплю и не понимаю как это сделать, даже с документацией. Поэтому все что мне остается, это обратиться к тому, кто понимает, прошу прощения за глупые вопросы

Comment: Это действительно очень (очень-очень) глупый вопрос... `cameraId` - это один из идентификаторов камер возвращаемый методом `String[] cameraIds=cameraManager.getCameraIdList()` неужели трудно посмотреть документацию, подумать?

Comment: Здесь все неправильно... вы проверяете наличие вспышки у всех камер, не сохраняя у какой конкретно камеры есть вспышка, потом неизвестно где пытаетесь взять `cameraId` и включить в ней вспышку. Логика должна быть такая - вы в цикле проверяете у какой камеры есть вспышка, далее зная ее `cameraId` включаете в ней вспышку :)

Comment: По-моему программирование это не ваше... Все очень печально. Вы не понимаете, что такое локальная переменная, вы не понимаете разницу между `String[]` и `String`

Comment: Сейчас, когда Android Studio не выдает никаких ошибок, мне стало действительно интересно в чем же моя ошибка, почему все таки фронтальная вспышка не хочет запускаться? Я спрашиваю у вас, потому что конкретно по теме вспышки мне больше не к кому обратиться. Прошу хотя бы намекнуть что не так)
https://imgur.com/a/8jP3sfn

Comment: Ну вот, теперь настало время познакомиться с отладчиком или освоить логгирование. Велкам в Android Studio (не в android, а именно в Android Studio)

Comment: Логи я тоже смотрел - ничего особенного, ошибок нет. Или я оттуда должен узнать id нужной камеры?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106526/discussion-between-barmaley-red-star-and-denis).

Comment: Как можно поступить в той ситуации, когда у фронтальной камеры отсутствует вспышка? То есть сам фонарик есть, и он включается встроенным приложением, но судя по всему как-то отдельно. Есть ли какие-то еще способы подобраться к этому фонарику?

Answer (score 1):

Перед тем как заняться включением самого фонарика, вам нужно предварительно прописать в манифесте разрешение на работу с ним:

```
 <permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
             android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
             android:protectionLevel="normal"
             android:label="@string/permlab_flashlight"
             android:description="@string/permdesc_flashlight" />
```

Дальше включение вспышки реализуется так:

```
Camera cam = Camera.open();     
Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
cam.setParameters(p);
cam.startPreview();
```

Вот есть подобные вопросы: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52562706/front-flash-light-in-android) и [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503480/use-camera-flashlight-in-android). Вообще фронтальной вспышкой оборудован далеко не каждый смартфон, поэтому я думаю что доступ к данной фиче делается отдельно производителем через какие-то костыли.

Comment: Все заработало, но по кнопке включается обычный фонарик, а не фронтальный. Или я вас неправильно понял и код выше и есть код от обычного фонарика?

Comment: как я уже говорил, фронтальный фонарик встречается нечасто поэтому вероятность того что вы сможете включить его используя стандартные способы слишком мала :( можно поискать как именно производитель работает с фронтальным фонариком